# Regex Splitting Incorrectly Formatted Addresses

Tags: python, regex, street-address

I'm **trying to correct address data where the street address and city/town information were appended without a space**.

The easiest way to identify split points is by looking for a road type (e.g. STREET, ST.) followed by a word, for example:

```
1201 WEST FRONT STREETCHESTER PA 19013-3496
```

However some splits occur on other words, such as SOUTH. We don't need to detect these for the moment.

```
703 6TH STREET SOUTHTEXAS CITY TX 77590
```

The following regex,

```
(ST(?:REET)?)\.?([A-Z]{3,})
```

works well for most examples, but will match ST REET in the second example. IIRC regexes were greedy by default, so I don't understand why this is happening. My understanding was that the first capture group should prevent the second from triggering. I've tried rewriting the regex as `(STREET|ST)\.?([A-Z]{3,})`, but this doesn't change anything.

Are there any ways of rewriting the regex or compilation flags that can help?

---

### Solution

For those interested, using Michal's regex as a starting point, the final regex I used was:

```
\s((?:(?!STREET|STATE)ST|STREET|LANE|LN|(?!DRIVE)DR|DRIVE|ROAD|RD|[0-9]+|(?!AVENUE)AVE|AVENUE|BOULEVARD|BLVD|HWY|HIGHWAY|WEST|EAST|(?!NORTHEAST|NORTHWEST)NORTH|(?!SOUTHEAST|SOUTHWEST)SOUTH|N\.|S\.|W\.|E\.)\.?)(?=[A-Z]{3,})
```

It handles Street, Lane, Drive, Avenue, Boulevard, Highway, and splits on cardinal directions for the EPA's TSCA data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use pattern:

```
( (?!STREET)ST|STREET)(?=[A-Z])
```

Explanation:

`(...)` - capturing group

- maatch space literally

`(?!...)` - negative lookahead assertion

`STREET` - matches `STREET` literally

`ST` - matches `ST` literally

`|` - alternation opeartor

`(?=...)` - positive lookahead assertion

`[A-Z]` - character class - match character from range `A-Z`, so any uppercse english character

Replacement pattern would be `\1` , so first capturing group (either `ST` or `STREET`) followed by space.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kd6dof/1)

Comment: This did the trick, thanks Michal! I had never heard of lookahead and lookbehind in regex, so this was a life saver.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that `(ST(?:REET)?)\.?([A-Z]{3,})` and `(STREET|ST)\.?([A-Z]{3,})` both match the single word `STREET` is that the regex has to match ***the whole pattern***, and note that the `.` is optional.

As the dot is optional, the regex can match either `STREET[A-Z]{3,}` or `ST[A-Z]{3,}`

The first can not match the word STREET only as there should be 3 or more characters after STREET, but the second pattern can match ST and 3 or more characters....matching STREET.

---

What you could do is match either STREET and 3 or more characters, or match ST. and 3 or more characters to not match the word STREET only

```
(STREET|ST\.)([A-Z]{3,})
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/P8gBIi/1)

---

Other possible options:

1.) Match ST and optionally match REET only if REET is not followed by a word boundary:

`\bST(?!REET\b)(?:REET)?`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/t1gPrj/1)

2.) Using the regex [PyPy module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) using an optional non capture group and a possessive quantifier followed by a non word boundary:

`\bST(?:REET)?+\B`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qUoz18/1)

Comment: Thank you for explanation, things make more sense now! Some of the examples have ST with no dot after and others have street with a dot after, so this approach will not work. I wound up using a modified version of Michal's answer

Comment: @FelixLabelle You might also use `\bST(?!REET\b)(?:REET)?` See  https://regex101.com/r/cGjnK0/1